# Error : Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65978 > 65536)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

hi Guys Im getting This errer when i tried to run my application . i investgated the issue and i found that the problem happen only when i add this google implementation . when i removed the implementaion the app worked just fine . why is that happening and what it is the solution

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'`

i dont know where the the cause of the probleme can any one help me by gaving me the solution or dercting me to any article

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must add the library in the app gradle :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

After, add in the defaultConfig of the app gradle :

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: @junaid_khalid tnx man

Comment: Glad to help please mark the answer as accepted if it really worked

Comment: yeah of course .

Comment: you could explain why this helps and why adding a dependency is necessary

Comment: A single dex file has a limit of classes it can have. So to increase the number of classes the simple way is to have multiple dex files. To have multiple dex files this library is important. @raquelhortab